# Marshalling utf8 encoded chinese characters from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm marshaling some Chinese characters which have the decimal representation (utf8) as

`228,184,145,230,161,148`

however when I receive this in C++ I end up with the chars

`-77,-13,-67,-37`

I can solve this using a `sbyte[]` instead of `string` in c#, but now I'm trying to marshal a `string[]` so I can't use this method. Anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

EDIT: more detailed code:

C#

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr inputFiles(IntPtr pAlzObj, string[] filePaths, int fileNum);

string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("myfolder", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string[] allFilesutf8 = allfiles.Select(i => Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(i))).ToArray();
IntPtr pRet = inputFiles(pObj, allfiles, allfiles.Length);
```

C++

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) char* inputFiles(Alz* pObj, char** filePaths, int fileNum);

char* massAdd(Alz* pObj, char** filePaths, int fileNum)
{
    if (pObj != NULL) {
        try{
            std::vector<const char*> imgPaths;
            for (int i = 0; i < fileNum; i++)
            {
                char* s = *(filePaths + i);
                //Here I would print out the string and the result in bytes (decimals representation) are already different.
                imgPaths.push_back(s);
            }

            string ret = pAlzObj->myfunc(imgPaths);
            const char* retTemp = ret.c_str();
            char* retChar = _strdup(retTemp);
            return retChar;
        }
        catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
            cout << "some runtime error " << e.what() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, something I found is that if I change the windows universal encoding (In language settings) to use unicode UTF-8, it works fine. Not sure why though.

When marshaling to unsigned char* (or unsigned char** as it's an array) I end up with another output, which is literally just 256+the nummbers shown when in char. `179,243,189,219`. This leads me to believe there is something happening during marshaling rather than a conversion mistake on the C++ side of things.

Comment: `Encoding.Default` is quite dangerous, usually not what you should be using, because it depends on systems settings and .NET version, not on the format the data actually has. -77 and 179 are equivalent (just reinterpretation of the same data), that does not indicate a bug.

Comment: I understand -77 and 179 are the same, but confused to how `228,184,145,230,161,148` can be converted to `-77,-13,-67,-37` or `179,243,189,219`. Also have used other encodings but that don't seem to work either

Comment: Well *that* part is a bug, and I expect using the wrong encoding is at fault (especially since you say that changing language setting helped). Whatever the actual encoding of the file is, is what you should use to read it (which encoding is that?)

Comment: @harold I found the problem, C# encodes as utf8 but c++ by default interprets it as GBK.

Comment: OK that's a bit different than I thought, there are different ways to fix this, using utf8 on the C++ side seems safest to me, using GBK on the C# is possible too, but then perhaps you should know that .NET Core really prefers utf8 (`Encoding.Default` will be utf8, regardless of your language setting, and getting the Encoding object for GBK is more difficult in .NET Core) so it's less future-proof to pass that data in GBK

Comment: Your c# code does not make any sense to me. A `string` is always a sequence of UTF16 characters. So `allFilesutf8` does not make sense, a utf8 encoded string should have the type `byte[]`. As far as I can tell, your encode-decode step should at best do nothing, and at worst mangle the text. And your variable names does not seem to match, what is  `testUtf8` exactly?

Comment: @JonasH Sorry that was a typo. I'm not too experienced with C# so I was not aware that string are always utf16. I've eliminated that. However I found that step wasn't causing issues, it was a C++ encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

That is because C++ strings uses standard `char` when stored. The `char` type is indeed signed and that makes those values being interpreted as negative ones.

I guess that traits may be handled inside the `<xstring>` header on windows (as far as I know). Specifically in:

```cpp
_STD_BEGIN
template <class _Elem, class _Int_type>
struct _Char_traits { // properties of a string or stream element
    using char_type  = _Elem;
    using int_type   = _Int_type;
    using pos_type   = streampos;
    using off_type   = streamoff;
    using state_type = _Mbstatet;
#if _HAS_CXX20
    using comparison_category = strong_ordering;
#endif // _HAS_CXX20
```

Comment: I don't directly use string in c++, I use char**. Then move the pointer for each element in the array.

Comment: @ZWang You are going to have to show some code. No-one can do anything other than guess if you are unwilling to show the code that is not working. That should be obvious, but apparently isn't.

Comment: `char**` still points to a `char*`, which points to a `char`, which is signed, leading to the same problem

Comment: @john I've added the code now

Comment: @AsulconS yes I realized that, I tried converting it to marshaling to `unsigned char**` but the same error happens, not sure why...

Comment: @ZWang While reading I saw that C# string cannot ensure that its inner type will be 8 bits wide, so I guess that it can be the reason of the problem (since a `wchar` type is twice as wide, assuming it detects Chinese characters and defaults to that)

Answer (score 0):

I have some ideas: You solve problem by using a sbyte[] instead of string in c#, and now you are trying to marshal a string[], just use List<sbyte[]> for string array.
I am not experienced with c++ but I guess there are another libraries for strings use one of them. Look this link, link show string types can marshalling to c#. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the marshaling. I think it was because as the data is transferred, the locale setting in the C++ dll was set to GBK (at least not UTF-8). The trick was to convert the incoming strings into UTF-8 from GBK, which I was able to do with the following function:

```
std::string gb_to_utf8(char* src)
{

    wchar_t* strA;
    int i = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, src, -1, NULL, 0);

    strA = (wchar_t*)malloc(i * 2);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, src, -1, strA, i);

    if (!strlen((char*)strA)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("error converting");
    }

    char utf8[1024];     //Unsure how long converted string could be, set as large number
    int n = 0;
    n = wcstombs(utf8, strA, sizeof(utf8));

    std::string resStr = utf8;

    free(strA);
    return resStr;
}
```

Also needed to set `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");` in order for the function above to work.